# Методы разрешения коллизий в веб-приложении

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, java-ee

Дано:
Веб-приложение. Серверная часть на Java.  Клиенты подключаются с помощью стандартного браузера и производят операции над данными. Число клиентов – до 5000. Операции – просмотр (поиск, сортировка, фильтрация), создание, удаление, изменение записей. Данные находятся в реляционной БД.
Возможны ситуации, когда более чем один пользователь вносит изменения в один объект модели данных. Эти изменения могут быть не конфликтующими (пользователи изменяют разные поля и это не нарушает целостность данных) и конфликтующими (пользователи изменяют одно и то же поле(поля) или же разные поля с нарушением целостности данных или связанные поля разных объектов так же с нарушением целостности).

Задача:
Реализовать подсистему обнаружения и разрешения коллизий в веб-приложении с высокой эффективностью, минимальными затратами на передачу данных между клиентом и сервером и минимальным эффектом на производительности клиентской и серверной части.

Вопросы:
1.       Стандартные / распространённые / общепринятые способы разрешения таких коллизий в веб-приложениях

2. Существующие реализации этих способов в продуктах / фреймворках / библиотеках и т.п.

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Ну заменили данные, и что? Я сейчас сохранил данные, вы через доли секунды - вы затерли мои изменения. Я сейчас сохранил данные, вы через несколько минут - вы опять затерли. Я сейчас сохранил данные - вы через несколько дней - и опять затерли. Какая разница между этими сценариями? По сути только одна - в первом случае вы будете видеть старые данные. Но что было бы, если бы вы увидели новые? Вы бы не стали сохранять изменения? Или как? Вы бы все равно сохранили их и все равно затерли бы мои изменения. Так что именно в этой схеме вас не устраивает?

Comment: Посмотрите как работает, например, svn - там же аналогичная ситуация: одновременно могут коммитить несколько человек. Если ошибок мерджа нет - значит все хорошо, если есть - покажет ошибку и не сохранит. Т.е. если изменяете объект - так меняйте, если пытаетесь изменить уже удаленный объект - покажите ошибку. Либо, например, можно ввести "ревизия объекта" и перед сохранением проверять, чтобы сохраненная ревизия совпадала с текущей. Если не совпадает - объект был изменен, значит не сохраняете и сообщаете об этом пользователю + показываете что именно было изменено

Comment: Я думаю универсального решения вам никто не даст. Такие вещи делаются под конкретную ситуацию. Если повторное изменение данных критично, то конечно можно запомнить что кто то открыл запись на редактирование и не давать другим заходить в правки, но тут же оказывается, что заблокировавший запись ушел пить чай и не закрыл окно. Сама структура базы должна проектироваться для минимизации коллизий, например нельзя вести денежный баланс просто как редактируемую сумму, нужна таблица со всеми операциями по счету, в которую возможно только добавление, хотите исправить ошибку - добавляете сторно запись

Comment: @ВОРОН, интересуют какие есть методы решения задачи:  Реализовать подсистему обнаружения и разрешения коллизий в веб-приложении с высокой эффективностью, минимальными затратами на передачу данных между клиентом и сервером и минимальным эффектом на производительности клиентской и серверной части.
какие методы чаще применяют, какие фреймворки использую.

Comment: начнем с того, что считать коллизией? Т.е. как определить, что здесь у нас коллизия, а вот здесь - нет. Как эти коллизии вы хотите разрешать? Затирать старые данные - нормально. Сколько должно пройти времени, чтобы вы это изменение считали нормальным? И если сохранение будет идти продолжительное время - что должны получить другие пользователи? В БД есть транзакции, есть различные уровни изоляции транзакций, может быть вас это устроит? Ведь они как раз и обеспечивают целостность данных

Comment: @ВОРОН, при сохранении данных объекта измененного пользователем система обнаруживает, что данные в базе уже изменены другим пользователем. Система должна предупредить пользователя и помочь ему разрешить противоречие.
Какие методы для решений существуют и как фреймворки лучше использовать

Comment: Типа такого: http://squirrel.pl/blog/2012/11/02/version-based-optimistic-concurrency-control-in-jpahibernate/

Comment: А что если поступить в стиле MS Office? Держать массив с IDшниками всех ячеек которые открыты для редактирования в данный момент. Если кто-то пытается открыть туже ячейку - предупреждать... ну а там поступать уже как вам нужнее.